# Separate each entry in an array and put in its own cell

Tags: excel, vba

A cell consists of an array that looks similar to this:

> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

How do I put each individual one into its own cell?

For example; 0 in C1, 1 in D1, 2 in E1 and so forth.

Comment: remove the brackets and use text-to-columns

Answer (score 4):

Put the values into a variant array and put them on the worksheet.

```
dim arr as variant

arr = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

with worksheets("sheet1")
    .range("C1").resize(1, ubound(arr)+1) = arr
end with
```

Comment: elegant answer.